# How come the Python's logging module doesn't follow PEP8 conventions?

Tags: python, logging, pep8, python-logging

This is is just a curiosity with historical purposes:

I was wondering if someone knows why the very widely used (and core module) [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger)  doesn't follow the Python's [PEP-8 naming convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).

For instance, in

```
>>> import logging
>>> log = logging.getLogger("hello")
```

I would expect it to be `get_logger`, but it isn't.

When it comes to [function names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names), the PEP8 standard says:

> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the
>   prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards
>   compatibility.

Was that the case? If so, with what other `logging` thingy it had to maintain backwards compatibility? Or was it just that the developers of `logging` felt like using camel-case naming?

Of course, the module is well documented and is not a big deal **at all**. I'm just curious.

Comment: Because historically, not all modules were developed *within* the Python standard library, and not all authors follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `logging` module was developed by a [separate company](https://web.archive.org/web/20140729094734/https://www.red-dove.com/python_logging.html) in 2001, and was heavily based on Log4j. As such it follows the naming conventions the original author picked, which mirror the Log4j choices; the latter has a [`getLogger()` method too](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Hierarchy.html#getLogger(java.lang.String)).

Not until a year later did [PEP 282](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0282/) propose to add it to the standard library, by which time the naming convention was set in stone.

It is a [known issue with the package](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LoggingPackage), but it is not the only package to violate the PEP. From the linked Wiki:

> PEP8 says - consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is most important.
>
> - So True, but can't not be changed, because of backward compatibility. logging2 maybe. -- techtonik
>
>   - It's a low priority right now, unless there's an initiative to ensure the rest of the stdlib is made to conform to PEP8. -- VinaySajip

Last but not least, the [styleguide itself](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) has this to say on applying styleguides:

> #### A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds
>
> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is most important.
>
> But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don't hesitate to ask!
>
> In particular: do not break backwards compatibility just to comply with this PEP!

'Fixing' `logging` would break backwards compatibility, which is just not worth it.

Comment: Many modules provide both versions of API (uglyCase and python_case) exactly for backwards compatibility.

Comment: 'Not fixing' `logging` (and others), i.e. not providing sane aliases while keeping BC, is the reason why PHP is still mocked.

Comment: @rr: there are many more reasons to mock PHP than just their inconsistency in naming.