# How can I get formatter string from a logging.formatter object in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I want to make a logging manager gui. Basically I want to get the tree structure of loggers and show their level and formatter in a pyqt gui. How can I get the format string from a formatter associated a handler object?

eg:

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger('myLogger')

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
_logger.addHandler(ch)
_logger.propagate=0
```

Now I have the `_logger`, how can I get string `'%(name)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s'` from the `logging.Formatter` object?

```
>>> _logger.handlers[0]
<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x13807610>
>>> _logger.handlers[0].formatter
<logging.Formatter object at 0x13807690>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`logging.Formatter` instances have a `_fmt` attribute:

```
>>> _logger.handlers[0].formatter
<logging.Formatter object at 0x102c72fd0>
>>> _logger.handlers[0].formatter._fmt
'%(name)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
```

You can always use `dir()` and `vars()` on objects to see what names might be available:

```
>>> vars(_logger.handlers[0].formatter)
{'_style': <logging.PercentStyle object at 0x102e6bbf0>, '_fmt': '%(name)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s', 'datefmt': None}
```

or you could just [look at the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c2e51a9985d77e88ea2f4cfe0a53d2befc29541f/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L600) (linked from the top of the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)).

Comment: If accessing an internal `_` attribute (which is generally a frowned-upon practice) is good enough for a million-pointer, it is good enough for me.

Comment: @PaulMcG: the logging module is [breaking style conventions in so many ways already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22993896), and there is no other option to access the format string. Needs must!

Comment: @PaulMcG: the `_` initial underscore convention is more of a warning: *Watch out, this attribute could be removed or change meaning in a future version without notice*. With the logging module however, I'm quite confident that if the attribute were ever to go away that there'd be a long deprecation period first, given the history of the package.

Comment: This comment was as much for my own benefit as for anyone else; I recently wrote code that accessed this `_fmt` field so that I could define a new formatter with some custom placeholders to it. 20 years' worth of Python coding habits gave me pause at committing such an act, but now I know I am in good company.