# What motivates the "no-alignment" policy of PEP 8?

Tags: python, pep8, pep

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has a [specific guideline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves) against whitespace around operators for alignment:

> No:
>
> ```
> x             = 1
> y             = 2
> long_variable = 3
> ```

If I understand correctly, the following is also recommended against:

```
salaries = {
    "Alice": 1500,
    "Bob":   1300,
    #      ^^ extra whitespace
}
```

**What are these specific recommendations useful for?**

Comment: Living projects see new variables and variable renames all the time. Are you going to re-align all those lines each time you add a new, longer variable name?

Comment: PEP-8 is just styling, they're not "useful" for anything. The authors just think that this is unnecessary and ugly.

Comment: As far as I know in most programming languages code should not be styled unnecessarly. If you add a new and longer variable you either have to change the spacing in every other variable or you stop respecting the spacing rules. Thus to keep it simple and clean you don't add spaces from the start

Comment: Put differently: it may *seem* like a good idea at the time, but you are assuming you only have to do this once. Each time you need to re-align those lines because you made a small change leads to a way bigger change in your version control system.

Comment: Another thing: the huge whitespace between the variable name and value can make it hard to see which goes with which. It's easy with just 3 lines, but try it with 20.

Comment: thank you for these answers. Why the downvotes though?

Comment: @Barmar many of the other PEP 8 guidelines improve clarity, how does that not count as useful?

Comment: Many are just because the concensus is that something is nicer, easier to read, etc. E.g. naming conventions. Also, consistency among programmers is its own reward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This rule was part of Guido’s original style essay [published in 1998](http://web.archive.org/web/19980526013513/http://www.python.org/doc/essays/styleguide.html), where he states:

> (Don't bother to argue with me on any of the above -- I've grown accustomed to this style over 15 years.)

So he didn’t directly motivate this one, but I can think of a few good reasons why you’d want to avoid doing this. Aligning code with spaces may *seem* like a good idea at the time, everything lining up neatly.

But most projects are not static. You *often* see that in real-life projects code is changed over time, and you may add or remove or rename entries in the list you so carefully aligned. You could easily end up with having to adjust the alignment of the whole block, because your change altered what is now the longest entry.

Such changes now cause you more work. You have to re-align the block. Your colleagues and your future self have to do more work reading the changeset in your version control system.

(And yes, a code formatter can do the re-aligning, but automated tools can't fix your code diff now touching a large number of lines that had _nothing to do with your commit other than being re-aligned).

Or, a later editor may balk at the prospect of having to re-align additional entries. The Wine project `dlls/msi/msipriv.h` file [started nicely aligned](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/6386edc5d8616e3aff9bd4f552cf9c30020bf522/dlls/msi/msipriv.h#L28-L32), but [over](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/commit/8e74308a10f2d0348de8d945a5525e3d9d810672#diff-153ff8bc2b08346d10b285acf174d00f) [time](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/commit/ccef56f2cc6c253eb43fd4e8821456c959f2e908#diff-153ff8bc2b08346d10b285acf174d00f) [inconsistencies](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/commit/ca49aae61ec31b8f26ce8b3e0b9317a312819940#diff-153ff8bc2b08346d10b285acf174d00f) creep in and you [end up with a bit of a mess](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/ba9f3dc198dfc81bb40159077b73b797006bb73c/dlls/msi/msipriv.h#L47-L54).

Next, the alignment doesn't necessarily make code easier to read; with enough white-space in between, you can easily end up misreading what value goes with what name.

At the same time, PEP 8 is a *guideline*. The [document itself states](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds):

> A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds
>
> [...]
>
> However, know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best.

You need to make your own decisions as to when to use alignment *anyway*.

Some parts of the Python standard library [break this specific rule](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/21ab7744ae30bff24bcc9e075a96e98137b90a37/Lib/msilib/__init__.py#L14-L26) (and yes, that's a Python reflection of the Wine project example above; that example was [imported from an external project years ago](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/fbab90e95bf6403269d702e8e85ef3a6eceafbb0)), and there are other examples of [broken PEP8 rules there for historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993667/how-come-the-pythons-logging-module-doesnt-follow-pep8-conventions), but sometimes in *some, limited areas*, breaking the rules *can* make sense.

Comment: -1. I understand this reasoning originated decades ago but the "non-static code/re-aligning" argument is really obsolete in a time of widespread automated code formatting.

Comment: @DanielSteck so how would you like me to answer a question that asks why the rule is there? I’m simply stating history here, reporting on what motivations went into the rule. You are downvoting because you don’t agree that the rule exists? Not that I agree with your motivation as automated reformatting of markdown tables is a *huge* issue as you can’t make out what small change caused to complete table to be reformatted.

Comment: Don't take it personally when someone disagrees with your answer. I think this kind of answer, while historically accurate, is misleading in regards to modern SWE best practices. And the OP specifically asked about the rationale, not the historical context, and your answer elaborates on the rationale, so it's fair to comment on that? Markdown is an entirely separate language so not sure why you're bringing it up here.

Comment: @DanielSteck: Don't worry, I am not taking it personally. The OP asked for the rationale behind the PEP 8 guideline, which I provided, including where it came from. I did not author the styleguide, the history here **is the rationale**. I bring up MD tables as an example of a format that some automated tools will reformat to re-align columns, and serves as an example as to why I personally am against auto-aligning in code formatters. Just because you _can_ doesn't mean you _should_. Anyway, this discussion is not really about helping me improve my answer, so I'm dropping this conversation.

Comment: @DanielSteck: note: if you actually came with some proof to back your assertions, in the form of _other style guides that support aligning code, and / or documented rationales for such rules adopted by a mainstream project_, that would be far more valuable.