# Python xml.sax inconsistency in it's method naming

Tags: python, xml, naming-conventions, sax, pep8

As I understand methods in Python should always be lowercase with underscore (PEP8 naming convention).

Today I was using the *xml.sax* package for the first time and noticed that several methods are in CamelCase while others are in under_score.
Examples:

```
def make_parser(parser_list=()):

def parseString(string, handler, errorHandler=ErrorHandler()):

def startElement(self, name, attrs):
```

Where does this inconsistency come from? Is it grown historically or is there more behind it?

Comment: Related: [How come the Python's logging module doesn't follow PEP8 conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993667/how-come-the-pythons-logging-module-doesnt-follow-pep8-conventions)

Comment: Ah thanks, I see for backward compatibility. But still I would expect that there are some wrapper methods that follow the PEP8 naming convention.